# How to make a View clickable that's underneath another already clickable View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appwidget

It was hard to give a descriptive title for this question!

I have an app widget in which I have some clickable buttons (using RemoteViews and PendingIntents as needed for app widgets) that are difficult to tap at their current size. To work around this without having to resize the actual button, I have placed larger, invisible, clickable FrameLayouts over these buttons to increase the clickable area. This works well, except the buttons also have selectors connected to them so that the background color for the images change when tapped. This selector no longer works when the FrameLayout covers the buttons since it's now actually the FrameLayout that's being tapped, not the buttons.

My question is if there's a way to somehow make it "click through" the FrameLayout so that the selector for the button is still triggered, or any other clever workaround that achieves the same effect? Applying the selector on the FrameLayout itself will make the background change much too large.

Below is a simplified example of what I'm doing. The actual layout I'm using is more complex, so any solutions that requires changing the layout may be more difficult to do than it may seem here. Also, the reason the FrameLayout is placed in a RelativeLayout is so that I have more freedom with the placement.

EDIT

The FrameLayout is placed on top of two other layouts, which is why I can't simply place it under the button. It needs to cover a larger area. I'm hoping I won't have to redo the entire layout to fix this problem.

**LAYOUT**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_myButton_w"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size_myButton_h"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/selector" //NOT TRIGGERED! Covered by FrameLayout below. 
                android:src="@drawable/myButton" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                <!-- More stuff here! -->

            </RelativeLayout>

                 <!-- Even more stuff here! -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**SELECTOR**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/navy" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could place your FrameLayout ***below*** the button, rather than on top. That way if they hit the actual button, you get your selector triggered and if they miss the button and still hit the FrameLayout...well, your selector won't get triggered, but your FrameLayout click listener will still get called.

Comment: Good idea, but I forgot to make it clear in my question that the FrameLayout is actually on top of _two_ other layouts, and putting it inside one of these would make the area too small. If nothing else works, I will try to redo the layout so I can do as you suggest though.